# Zoho Auth-token response in json

Tags: json, zoho

I am using Zoho docs API and got a auth-token
https://www.zoho.com/docs/zoho-docs-api.html
The problem is that ,the response from Zoho is in text/plain format .
How can i get it in json format.

Comment: How did you get the `text/plain` format? I got JSON format only. Could you specify the API?

Comment: https://accounts.zoho.com/apiauthtoken/create?SCOPE=ZohoPC/docsapi&&DISPLAY_NAME=ZOHODOCS

Comment: https://accounts.zoho.com/apiauthtoken/nb/create?SCOPE=ZohoPC/docsapi&DISPLAY_NAME=ZOHODOCS&EMAIL_ID=username&PASSWORD=pass    This is the API mode to create authtoken. However authtoken will be text/plain format.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to get the result in json format, you can use php curl.

```
 <?php
    // Define your Zoho API credentials
    $client_id = 'your_client_id';
    $client_secret = 'your_client_secret';
    $redirect_uri = 'https://example.com/zoho-authentication.php';
    $scope = 'ZohoCRM.modules.ALL';
    
    // If the code parameter is present in the URL query string, then we have been
    // redirected back from the Zoho authorization page and we can proceed to
    // obtain the access token
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        // Retrieve the code parameter from the URL query string
        $code = $_GET['code'];
    
        // Define the token endpoint
        $token_url = 'https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/token';
    
        // Define the POST data to obtain the access token
        $post_data = array(
            'code' => $code,
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'client_secret' => $client_secret,
            'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        );
    
        // Initialize the cURL session
        $curl = curl_init();
    
        // Set the cURL options
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_data));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    
        // Execute the cURL request and store the response
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
        // Close the cURL session
        curl_close($curl);
    
        // Process the API response to obtain the access token
        $access_token = json_decode($response)->access_token;
    
        // Store the access token in a session variable for later use
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['zoho_access_token'] = $access_token;
    
        // Redirect the user to the home page of your application
        header('Location: https://example.com/home.php');
        exit();
    }
    
    // If the code parameter is not present in the URL query string, then we need to
    // redirect the user to the Zoho authorization page to grant permission for
    // our application to access their Zoho account
    else {
        // Define the authorization endpoint
        $auth_url = 'https://accounts.zoho.com/oauth/v2/auth';
    
        // Generate the authorization URL
        $auth_params = array(
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'scope' => $scope,
            'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
        );
        $auth_url .= '?' . http_build_query($auth_params);
    
        // Redirect the user to the authorization URL
        header('Location: ' . $auth_url);
        exit();
    }
    ?>
```